# Explain the difference between installing new Android apk and upgrading existing Android apk? how apk upgrade work?

Tags: android, installation, updates

i want to know how updation work? how its update specific file changes only?i mean that during updation ,does whole apk insatall again or only specific file change? and how its work?
I just want to know how android market does apk upgrade without user prompt and directly from the market site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google play store uses smart app updates. It calculates diff between old and new apk and downloads only those changes. See:

- [Smart App Updates on Google Play Store: how does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12860938/smart-app-updates-on-google-play-store-how-does-it-work)
- http://www.androidpolice.com/2012/08/16/google-flips-the-switch-on-smart-app-updates-in-the-play-store-video/

Comment: Thanks for reply but could you tell me please, how can i update my app from my server? will i have to download and re-install or any specific method is available?

Comment: If you are publishing to the Google play store, you can use version codes to upgrade your app. See: https://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/versioning.html

Comment: i dont want to publish in google play ,i want to give upgradation from my server

Comment: Then you'll have to come up with your own mechanisms and algorithms to do this. It will be very hard and complex to do this securely and reliably. I would advise publishing on the play store unless you have very good reasons not to do it.

Comment: Thanks Anup for giving valuable advice.