# Does Google Play store update redownload entire app?

Tags: android, python, google-play

Does anyone know how the Google Play store handles pushing updates to users?

I presume they either:

- Make users download a whole new apk, or
- Modify what's already on the user's phone, like Git would.

I ask because I'm working on something, using the [Pygame subset for android](http://pygame.renpy.org/) that would need to slightly change a small bit of it's content every so often, but would rather not force users to download python/pygame every time (and would rather not have to build my own online updater into the app).

Thanks in advance.

P.S. - It's probably not relevant, but here's an early version of the app.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nl.cogsci.OpenSesameMobile&hl=en_GB

Comment: Long story short, they use a Git-type system:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12860938/smart-app-updates-on-google-play-store-how-does-it-work

http://www.androidcentral.com/what-are-delta-updates-and-why-youll-forget-about-it-tomorrow

http://news.cnet.com/8301-1023_3-57495096-93/google-play-enables-smart-app-updates-conserving-batteries/

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the answers.

After a little more research myself, I've found that Google do actually use the latter, Git style system, under the label of 'Delta Updates', or 'smart updates', although it doesn't seem to mentioned in the page @TrevorAnderson linked. It seems that Google doesn't document how this works, but takes care of the whole process server side, without input from the developer.

#### Sources

---

[Smart App Updates on Google Play Store: how does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12860938/smart-app-updates-on-google-play-store-how-does-it-work)

http://www.androidcentral.com/what-are-delta-updates-and-why-youll-forget-about-it-tomorrow

http://news.cnet.com/8301-1023_3-57495096-93/google-play-enables-smart-app-updates-conserving-batteries/

---

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when we update any application, it will download the new APK. 
The old app is uninstalled then the newly downloaded apk is installed.
In this process all preferences, databases, etc. are preserved.