# Services that update Google Play Store Apps

Tags: android, upload, google-play, updates

I am an Android developer and was planning to upload my first android app on the play store.

Being an android user for the past 4 years, I noticed that some apps update differently. I saw that some apps like Facebook, Instagram and other top apps only download 50-60% of their original size while updating.

I don't know about other apps, but I want to know that **is there any different format in which I have to upload the app so that my downloaders don't have to download the full app(around 12 MB).**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is default behavior.

Comment: @NiekHaarman So they first unpack our apps then find the file which is updated and then upload that and then repack it? Very unlikely.

Comment: The play store calculates a delta (difference) between the two apk files - only the changed data is downloaded and then applied to your existing apk to create an exact 1:1 version of the updated apk. So this **does** happen by default. No unpacking is done since they can not re-sign the apk with your key. The size of the delta can sometimes be larger than the "changed files" in an updated apk, because it does the comparison on the final apk (zip file).

Comment: @free3dom Why don't you post this in the answer? And also mention your source. Thanks

Comment: There are no official sources, but there have been many tests done by various people. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12877791/1326821) for a good description.