# android google play market application procedure

Tags: android, google-play, apk

I have a question about updating installed application.

Does android download whole apk file when updating from market? or has another way to doing it?

Comment: Yes. App is downloaded again and replaced instead of existing one in same package name. DB and other app data don't go away. Why do you want to know about this ? Make clear your question or the purpose behind it .

Comment: But when I update FaceBook app, it says 18Mb, but after finishing around 10 Mb, it finished updating. I strongly feel they have some tricks, insted of replacing the whole code.

Comment: No, typically it won't download the entire new APK - just the parts that have changed. You can read more by searching for "android smart app updates", or e.g. in [this StackOverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12860938/smart-app-updates-on-google-play-store-how-does-it-work).

Answer (score 1):

When you update any app from playstore, it **downloads again**-

**But it keeps all the previous stored data (like shared preference,SQLite,obb files or files inside the android/data)**.

Comment: _"it downloads again"_ is a bit vague, considering that the OP wanted to know whether the _whole_ APK will be downloaded or not.