# Updating the signed store version of my app crashes on startup

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity

I'm attempting to put out a new ver of my app.  If I have the previous google play version installed and update to a new signed version it installs fine but crashes on startup.  If I delete the previous version and install it works fine. I'm worried about the support nightmare to tell all my users to delete and re-install my game.

Why would having a previous version and upgrading cause a crash where a clean install does not?

Thanks for any pointers

Crash Log:

```
01-16 04:33:45.144 16372-16372/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.lonelystarsoftware.upwords, PID: 16372
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.lonelystarsoftware.upwords/com.lonelystarsoftware.upwords.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class com.lonelystarsoftware.upwords.GameBoard
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class com.lonelystarsoftware.upwords.GameBoard
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class com.lonelystarsoftware.upwords.GameBoard
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
 at com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.app.SlidingActivity.setContentView(SlidingActivity.java:61)
 at com.lonelystarsoftware.upwords.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:103)
 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
 Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 13: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f0300c6 a=-1}
 at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:925)
 at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4202)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:579)
 at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:248)
 at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:244)
 at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:240)
 at com.lonelystarsoftware.upwords.GameBoard.<init>(GameBoard.java:86)
```

XML of GameBoard:

```
<com.lonelystarsoftware.upwords.GameBoard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:autofit="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/gameBoard"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="?navbarColor"
android:clickable="true"
tools:context=".MainActivity" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/master"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/topLinear"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="?boardColor"
    android:clipChildren="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:background="?toolbarColor">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="5" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="10">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="10"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:contentDescription="logo"
                    android:src="@drawable/upwords_logo_bevel_2016"
                    android:visibility="visible" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/logo2016"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="10"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:contentDescription="logo"
                    android:src="@drawable/upwords_logo_2016"
                    android:visibility="visible" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="5"></FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonMenu"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/game_button"
            android:backgroundTint="?buttonColor"
            android:minHeight="35dp"
            android:minWidth="70dp"
            android:onClick="toggleMenu"
            android:text="MENU"
            android:textColor="?buttonTextColor"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageLogo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:contentDescription="logo"
            android:src="@drawable/upwords_background"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageLogo_mask"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:contentDescription="logo"
            android:src="@drawable/upwords_mask"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonChat"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/game_button"
            android:backgroundTint="?buttonColor"
            android:minHeight="35dp"
            android:minWidth="70dp"
            android:onClick="toggleChat"
            android:text="CHAT"
            android:textColor="?buttonTextColor"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/scoreContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="5">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/scoreGroup"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="?scoreBackgroundColor"
            android:minHeight="35dp" >

            <com.lonelystarsoftware.upwords.ScoreArea
                android:id="@+id/scoreArea"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="center_vertical">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/scoreCapsuleGroup"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/scoreCapsule1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical" >

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/turnIndicator1"
                            android:layout_width="20dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:src="@drawable/your_turn_indicator" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/scoreName1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/score_name_label"
                            android:ellipsize="end"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:maxLines="1"
                            android:maxWidth="100dp"
                            android:text="Player1"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                            android:textColor="?scoreLabelNameTextColor"
                            android:backgroundTint="?scoreLabelNameBackgroundColor" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/scoreValue1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="@drawable/score_value_label"
                            android:ellipsize="end"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:maxLines="1"
                            android:text="0"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                            android:textColor="?scoreLabelScoreTextColor"
                            android:backgroundTint="?scoreLabelPointsBackgroundColor" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/scoreCapsule2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/scoreCapsule1"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/scoreCapsule1"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/turnIndicator2"
                            android:layout_width="20dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                            android:src="@drawable/your_turn_indicator"
                            android:visibility="gone" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/scoreName2"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/score_name_label"
                            android:ellipsize="end"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:maxLines="1"
                            android:maxWidth="100dp"
                            android:text="Player2"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                            android:textColor="?scoreLabelNameTextColor"
                            android:backgroundTint="?scoreLabelNameBackgroundColor" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/scoreValue2"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:background="@drawable/score_value_label"
                            android:ellipsize="end"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:maxLines="1"
                            android:text="0"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                            android:textColor="?scoreLabelScoreTextColor"
                            android:backgroundTint="?scoreLabelPointsBackgroundColor" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                </RelativeLayout>
            </com.lonelystarsoftware.upwords.ScoreArea>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/under_shadow" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.lonelystarsoftware.upwords.TileBoard
        android:id="@+id/tileBoard"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="62"
        android:background="?boardColor">

    </com.lonelystarsoftware.upwords.TileBoard>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/tileTrayLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="?trayColor"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="13"
        android:measureWithLargestChild="false">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/tileTrayGroup"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_gravity="center">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <com.lonelystarsoftware.upwords.TileTray
                    android:id="@+id/tileTray"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:background="?trayColor"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="false">
                </com.lonelystarsoftware.upwords.TileTray>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tilesLeft"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:gravity="top|right"
                    android:text="Tiles Left: 0"
                    android:textColor="?tilesLeftTextColor"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
                    android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="false"
                    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Small"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
                    android:elegantTextHeight="false"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ImageView03"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="10dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:src="@drawable/under_shadow" />


        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:background="?toolbarColor"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonShuffle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/game_button"
            android:minHeight="35dp"
            android:minWidth="100dp"
            android:text="SHUFFLE"
            android:textColor="?buttonTextColor"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:backgroundTint="?buttonColor" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonSwap"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/game_button"
            android:minHeight="35dp"
            android:minWidth="100dp"
            android:text="SWAP"
            android:textColor="?buttonTextColor"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:backgroundTint="?buttonColor" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonRecall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/game_button"
            android:minHeight="35dp"
            android:minWidth="100dp"
            android:text="RECALL"
            android:textColor="?buttonTextColor"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:backgroundTint="?buttonColor" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonPlay"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/game_button"
            android:minHeight="35dp"
            android:minWidth="100dp"
            android:text="NO NEXT GAME"
            android:textColor="?buttonTextColor"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:backgroundTint="?buttonColor" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/computerProgress"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

</RelativeLayout> <com.lonelystarsoftware.upwords.GameBoard>
```

Comment: post your xml file . your error log pointing out xml error .

Comment: Are you, or did you just start using AppCompat ? Please mind that without the xml code we can't do much.

Comment: Thank.  I added xml for GameBoard (which it appears to be complaining about).  It's probably my most complex view, it's the main game board of my app

Comment: It calls Delta Update: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12860938/smart-app-updates-on-google-play-store-how-does-it-work ; Please put both Old and New XML file of this section.

Comment: Juan, I didn't just start using AppCompat

Comment: The XML you have posted does not have a closing tag for `<com.lonelystarsoftware.upwords.GameBoard`

Comment: Hmm.. I do have a closing tag which shows up when I edit this post, just not showing in the code block.  If I remove the new line (which I just did).. it shows up.  some stack overflow editor issue

Comment: On the Delta update.  I'm actually downloading the previously signed APK from the Play Store in the Developer Console.  I then delete my game from the simulator and install this APK.  Then I install my new signed APK, the next version, over that one.  that's how I'm testing what my users will experience (I think).   I'm installing by doing: adb install -r release/upwords-release.apk for example

Comment: As fast as posting Old and New XML. I just looked at a diff.. they are identical except some of the statements have switched order.  So technically it's changed but all the same info is in there.  I can try rolling that back (those changes weren't intentional , seems the editor decided to reorder some statements)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not sure why this was happening but I started rolling back any new changes I'd made to my app.  I had experimented converting some ListViews to RecyclerViews but didn't end up making that change.  As a result I still had the following in build.gradle:

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
```

I removed those lines and any of the test code that was using it and now my app upgrades fine.  I'd love to know why.. what if I decide to go with recyclerviews in the future? How would I go about added that and maintain upgradability?